# squid cache_peer_access made error?

Tags: squid, cache

Sorry, i'm learning Squid.
This is my squid key config

```
cache_peer 192.168.157.201 parent 3128 0 carp  no-netdb-exchange login=PASS  http11
cache_peer 192.168.157.202 parent 3128 0 carp  no-netdb-exchange login=PASS  http11
cache_peer 192.168.157.203 parent 3128 0 carp  no-netdb-exchange login=PASS  http11
cache_peer 192.168.157.207 parent 3333 0 carp  no-netdb-exchange login=PASS  http11

acl display_addr dstdomain .ip.cn
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny dispaly_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.202 deny dispaly_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.203 deny dispaly_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 allow all
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.202 allow all
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.203 allow all
```

but when i start my squid i get this error.

```
FATAL: Bungled common.frontend.conf line 22: cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny    dispaly_addr
Squid Cache (Version LUSCA_HEAD-r14809): Terminated abnormally.
FATAL: Bungled common.frontend.conf line 22: cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny dispaly_addr
Squid Cache (Version LUSCA_HEAD-r14809): Terminated abnormally.
FATAL: Bungled common.frontend.conf line 22: cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny dispaly_addr
Squid Cache (Version LUSCA_HEAD-r14809): Terminated abnormally.
FATAL: Bungled common.frontend.conf line 22: cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny dispaly_addr
Squid Cache (Version LUSCA_HEAD-r14809): Terminated abnormally.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typo:

```
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny dispaly_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.202 deny dispaly_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.203 deny dispaly_addr
```

should be:

```
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.201 deny display_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.202 deny display_addr
cache_peer_access 192.168.157.203 deny display_addr
```

(display_addr spelt incorrectly)

Comment: Sorry for my floosh!